Next.js 14 app strategy to allow users upload a .crt and .key certificates to be used on third party API requests
I've been developing a Next.js 14 app using (next-auth, prisma, mongodb, AWS S3).
Basically, the app connects to an external third party banking API that requires the use of mTLS protocol, so I have to pass both the .crt and .key certificates provided by the API service with along an access_token to start making requests to the API.
The way I'm dealing with that flow now, is using axios to create an instance where I include the certificates beforehand... Here's the basic flow:

After authenticating the user (next-auth / Google), the app calls the external API and requests an access_token
The access_token is stored on database (prisma <-> mongodb) under the user's account
The access_token is made available in next-auth session
The access_token is also set to axios global defaults

Using axios global defaults such as axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = access_token is how i make further requests to the external API
Beyond connecting the external banking API, the app has also its own API for managing things like Users, Organizations, Employees, Integrations, Payrolls etc.
I was wondering about the possibility of storing the certificates uploaded by the user on AWS S3 and then save a reference to them under the app's "Integrations" database table.
Organizations (which belong to a user) can enable "Integrations" to add and remove additional functionality across the app.
So for an specific Integration module I need to allow the user to upload the certificates and then use those certificates for further API requests.
Here's my initial prisma schema: https://prisma-editor.vercel.app/schema/6905?token=clzwtv2bz0000h9zujb6p69bv
Thanks in advance for any ideas or directions regarding this issue.
